# Homebrew Install error

Tags: redis, installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install redis with Homebrew. I'm getting the error below:

```
brew install redis

==> Downloading http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
==> make -C /private/tmp/redis-1Tw6/redis-2.6.14/src CC=cc
Failed to execute: make

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I've run brew doctor and brew update without any issue. XCode CLT is also up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: try deleting "/Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz" and see if it works

Comment: Just tried deleting the file but getting the same error. Thanks though

Comment: I just ran exactly same command on my Mac and it worked, can you try running make command? make -C /private/tmp/redis-1Tw6/redis-2.6.14/src CC=cc

Comment: I just ran make -C /private/tmp/redis-1Tw6/redis-2.6.14/src CC=cc in terminal. 

I'm getting make: *** /private/tmp/redis-1Tw6/redis-2.6.14/src: No such file or directory.  Stop.

I don't think I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-cleanly-remove-homebrew) and everything works great now.